# Emails not being received on cross domain

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending an email from email@mydomain.com (sample only). The problem is when email is programmatically sent.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
......
public function sendCredentials(){
    dispatch(new MailUserCredentialsJob($this));
}
```

If the recipient is in the same domain as the sender `recipient@mydomain.com`, it is being received. While if it's cross domain or other domain it is not being received. Tried manually sending email to other domains like `@icloud.com`, `@gmail.com` etc and it works. Anyone encountered problems with this?